# Trying to specify multiple wildcards in a countifs function for Excel

Tags: excel, wildcard, countif

I am working on a data sheet that has almost 300,000 rows by about 40 columns.
I have a **`countifs`** function to count the number of rows that have an entry ranging from **`"A1"`** through **`"A5"`** for each letter **`A-G`** in a particular column.

I have broken out analysis on separate sheets to pull data for each row for each separate letter A-G using **`countifs(range,"other data","F?")`** (I know its simplified).

I need to create a new sheet that excludes any row with an A value in it.
I tried **`countifs(range,"other data", range,{"B?","C?","D?","E?","F?","G?"})`** and it only returns the count for the outside values (**`B and G`**), how do I get Excel to count all of those other values as well?  I would like to keep this format because to create the sheets for B-G, I just used the find and replace to replace "A?" with "B?" and so on for the other sheets.

I would like to just replace "B?" with whatever works to count the number of rows that have B-G in that particular column.

Comment: You could just use 6 SUMIFS statements, 1 for each letter. More cumbersome, yes, but perhaps 'simpler'.

Comment: Your formula will count any two characters that start with [B-G] and not limited just to [B1-G5].  Maybe that's OK with your data set.  If not, you will need a more complex formula, or a User Defined Function.  I have posted an answer showing how to use your formula with the array constant for a criteria.

Answer (score 2):

You countifs formula, with an array constant for criteria, returns an array of values.  But what you want is the SUM of that array.  So:

```
sum(countifs(range,"other data", range,{"B?","C?","D?","E?","F?","G?"}))
```

Without the sum function, you will only see the value of the first element of that array.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is the wrong answer, but I'll say it anyway. Why can't you use

```
=COUNTIFS(Range,"<>A?")
```

Or are there other possible values that you want to exclude?

In which case you should be able to use this for A

```
=COUNTIFS(Range,">=B1",Range,"<=G5")
```

and for B1-B5

```
=COUNTIFS(Range,">=A1",Range,"<=A5")+COUNTIFS(Range,">=C1",Range,"<=G5")
```

which can be modified for C, D, E and F

and this for G

```
=COUNTIFS(Range,">=G1",Range,"<=G5")
```